# How can I omit Helvetica with TCPDF?

Tags: php, file, pdf, fonts, tcpdf

I'm making a PDF with TCPDF, and I'm trying to make the file as small as possible.  The font I'm using is Open Sans.  I'm not (intentionally, at least) using Helvetica anywhere in the PDF.  When I view the included fonts with Adobe Reader in my outputted PDF file, both Open Sans and Helvetica are listed.  I have noticed that if I `AddFont()` other fonts, the outputted PDF gets bigger.

To save space, how can I tell TCPDF to not include Helvetica in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Helvetica font is added by TCPDF for two reasons:

1. On initialization the TCPDF class sets the default font to Helvetica (in the constructor) and therefore adds this font to the fonts list of the document.

*For older versions:*
To prevent this, you can edit the file `config/tcpdf_config.php` and change the constant `PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN` to your desired default font name (should be around line 155). Note that you must not use any core font because they will never be embedded.

*For newer versions:*
Define `PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN` with your desired default font name *before* including the TCPDF files. Example:

```
define('PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN', 'freesans');
include_once 'path/to/tcpdf.php';
```

2. TCPDF adds an invisible link "Powered by www.tcpdf.org" at the bottom of the page.

To prevent this you have to use an override class like this:

```
class MyPdf extends TCPDF {

    public function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4', $unicode=true, $encoding='UTF-8', $diskcache=false, $pdfa=false) {
        // call parent constructor
        parent::__construct($orientation, $unit, $format, $unicode, $encoding, $diskcache, $pdfa);
        // disable the tcpdf link
        $this->setTcpdfLink(false);
    }

    /**
     * Allows to disable the invisible "Powered by www.tcpdf.org" link at the bottom of the page.
     * @param type $tcpdflink
     */
    public function setTcpdfLink($tcpdflink = true) {
        $this->tcpdflink = $tcpdflink ? true : false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't '$this->tcpdflink = false' somewhere from inside the (sub)class not work? This seems a bit convoluted to me.

Comment: Because TCPDF adds the default font anyways to the PDF file in the constructor. Therefore you need to set the default font before initializing any TCPDF or derived class.

Comment: Okay, but I thought it might be a bit simpler to just add  '$this->tcpdflink = false' in the overridden constructor instead of adding a special function for it. Well, perhaps just a case of good coding practice at your end. Great find, BTW. Not documented, and Nicola did his best to hide the string from the sources.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The above solution assumes that you don't use an override, thus enabling to set the variable "from the outside".

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Those two steps weren't quite enough.  After changing `PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN` and changing the constructor, I did a find/replace from "helvetica" to "opensans".  That finally removed Helvetica completely.  Surprisingly, that only saved me about 500 bytes, though.

Answer (score 1):

The Helvetica font is one of the standard 14 core PDF fonts, so it is not embedded in the PDF when it is used. If you look in the TCPDF fonts directory you will notice that the Helvetica file only contains a description of the font and **not** a copy of the font. Therefore it shouldn't be significantly increasing the file size.

### Solution

The Helvetica font is set as the default font in the TCPDF config files. From my testing, it appears that this causes it to be set as a font in the generated PDF files even when it is not used. Changing the default fonts in your TCPDF configuration files should prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have to face the same issue. I have tried the **JOR** solution. its correct but it still shows the Helvetica font family in my pdf.

for my pdf, I am using SVG image.so it displays the Helvetica . in the tcpdf.php protected property called $svgstyles has the SVG font family as Helvetica.

Answer (score 0):

Just find $tcpdflink in tcpdf.php and make that variable false. This works for me